# Model a ISA relation in MySQL with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, model, foreign-keys

How to model an ISA class?
A 'Persoon' ISA 'Student' or a 'Docent', how do you model this in MySQL?
I tried to make a Persoon class, with 2 field and then you can put the ID of the student / docent in the correct field. The other one is zero.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Docent` (
  `docent_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,,
  PRIMARY KEY (`docent_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persoon` (
  `naam` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `wachtwoord` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `docent_id` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
  KEY `docent_id` (`docent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Student` (
  `student_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentnummer` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `niveau` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `notities` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When adding the foreign keys, as shown below I get a #1452 error. I looked it up, but did not find how to solve it.

```
ALTER TABLE  `Persoon` ADD CONSTRAINT  `Persoons_student_id` FOREIGN KEY (  `student_id` ) REFERENCES  `software`.`Student` (`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
ALTER TABLE  `Persoon` ADD CONSTRAINT  `Persoons_docent_id` FOREIGN KEY (  `docent_id` ) REFERENCES  `software`.`Docent` (`docent_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Gives this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`software`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-c0_54eea'>, CONSTRAINT `Persoons_student_id` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `Student` (`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASC)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it backwards - a FOREIGN KEY from the "specific" table should reference the "general" table.

In your case: `Docent` should reference `Person` and `Student` should also reference `Person`, similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
  person_id int(4) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- Other fields...
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (
  student_id int(4) unsigned,
  -- Other fields...
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
    REFERENCES Person (person_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Docent (
  docent_id int(4) unsigned,
  -- Other fields...
  PRIMARY KEY (docent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (docent_id)
    REFERENCES Person (person_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Insert a new student by:

- First inserting a row into `Person` and getting the generated `person_id` (e.g. via [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)).
- And than using that same value for `student_id` when inserting a row into `Student`.

Ditto for docent.